# send multi line txt doc content in an email body message+c#

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to read a multi line txt document and trying to send an email message with the same multi line content as in the text document using c#

I tried using the File.ReadAllText method but that reads the entire txt document content in one string and puts it in the email body without the line separation.

Let's say a txt doc has the following lines

> a
>   bcd
>   efgh

I want the mail message to be sent in the same format.

Code Specific to Send email is,
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

```
               mail.Body = File.ReadAllText(path);

                var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                    {
                        smtp.Host = "abc";
                        smtp.Port = 25;
                        smtp.EnableSsl = false;
                        smtp.DeliveryMethod = system.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

                        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");

                    }

                    smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: It's probably worth showing us the code you're using to send the email please. Putting line breaks in the string is the correct thing to do, except if you're sending it as HTML then the recipient will ignore them as just whitespace, and if it is sent as text but your recipient has an email client that tries to join lines together intelligently then it might be doing that even if you did send the line breaks. The solution to that is usually the same as here on StackOverflow: add three spaces to the end of each line where you want to force a break, as I've edited into your example.

Comment: You may be able to use `File.ReadAllText().Split('\n');` which will split the rows based on each new line, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @Rup thank you for the response. Based off your suggestion i did add three spaces before the line break. Email still comes off as one continuous text. The code specific to email send has been added above.

Comment: @Symon File.ReadAllText().Split('\n') throws an error. Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to string

Answer (score 0):

Please, use StreamReader instance with ReadLine() method to read document line by line. Also you can use newline separator to format your document in right way.

Comment: I don't follow. You're asking him to read it line by line and then re-add the newline separators?

Comment: File can be too big to load all lines into memory. So he can load line by line do validation,filtering etc and prepare text for email.

Comment: Maybe that's true in general, but [SmtpClient's MailMessage.Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.body) doesn't accept a streaming body for messages larger than you can fit into memory. You might be able to rig something up using Mailkit/Mimekit, but I'd be surprised. And I doubt many mail servers would let you send messages that large, e.g. gmail's limit is 25MB.